# Android notifications in another language

Tags: android, notifications

In my android app I am using Firebase messaging via topics. I am ocassionally sending notifications to my application via Postman to the users which are in that topic:

```
  "notification" : {
  "title" : "some title in local lang",
     "body" : "some text in local lang",
      "sound" : "default"
    },
"data": {
   "title": "some title in local lang",
     "message": "some msg in local lang",
     "sound" : "default"
  }
```

I just want to show at least the notification title in english language if the user has switched the language in my app to english.

This is the MyFirebaseMessagingService  class, where I tried to work with the notification text, but it doesn't work, it always shows the notification in the sent language, not the app language:

```
 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String title = "";
        if (Objects.requireNonNull(remoteMessage.getNotification()).getTitle() != null){
            title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        }

        String message = "";
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() != null){
            message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        }

        String lng = readLang();

        if (lng.equals("en")) {title="New object added";}

        if (readState()) {
        sendNotification(title, message);

    } }


    private void sendNotification(String title, String body) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Novinky.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0 /* Request code */,
                i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        String lng = readLang();

        if (lng.equals("en")) {title="New object added";}

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
                getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notify)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(sound)
                .setContentIntent(pi);

        NotificationManager manager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        assert manager != null;
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
    private boolean readState() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("State", true);
    }

    private String readLang() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        return sharedPreferences.getString("hrady_langx", "sk");
    }
}
```

So in both cases (sendNotification and onMessageReceived) I check if (lng.equals("en")) and then define an english title, but this works not...

Comment: Your `MyFirebaseMessagingService` will only be called if your app is already in the foreground. For what you're wanting to do you'll be better saving the language the user has the app running in, then sending messages in the correct language for the user.

Comment: I see, but how do I send also a message in Postman to the users with another language as I can't check who has another language in Postman. The language is saved in sharedPreferences in my app. Maybe I can create a new Firebase topic only for the users with other language and then send message for both topics from Postman, one in english, one in local lang. But not sure it's a good idea, always registering and unregistering to the topics, if the user switches the language.

Comment: And I am also sending DATA - Data messages, which can trigger the onMessageReceived() callback even if your app is in foreground/background/killed. I've also find somewhere to try to use: body: {"en": "English Message","sv": "Swedish Message"}, but I don't think this will work

Comment: Ah, missed that, apologies. If you're sending it like that, then you can set the message to content from the data, and have a key value pair of en:message sv:message.  I'd still suggest to have this managed by an API though, sending to just one language at a time then you can get better analytics of how it's received depending on your audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I found out - I am now sending only DATA payload, created a notification channel and then I can handle title and message inside onMessageReceived. Now this is working as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, to use title_loc_key instead of title in Postman data.

Resources/values/strings.xml (default file)

```
<string name="notification_title_string">Local title</string>
```

Resources/values-en/strings.xml (English strings file)

```
<string name="notification_title_string">English title</string>
```

On the payload instead of using title and message / body keys, we will use title_loc_key to represent the key for our localized title and body_loc_key to represent the key for our localized message.

When sending the payload would look like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "title_loc_key": "notification_title_string",
        "body_loc_key": "notification_message_string"
     },
     "priority": "high",
     "condition": "'test' in topics"
}
```

I will test it when I send the next notification.

Comment: unfortunately this is not working, neither the version with title_loc_key, neither body: {"en": "English Message","sv": "Swedish Message"}